# android emulator nexus api 17 storage always crash

Tags: android, android-emulator, storage

I can not access the files. No file is stored. I tried opening Option>Storage but it crashes. However, this is my configuration.

Please help!

[image]

This is my device monitor. I can't access the file.

[image]